# <hr> tag not showing based on Bootstrap version

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4, cdn

```
<head>
    <title>Startup</title>

    <!-- Required meta tags -->
    <!-- Recommended to always add them -->
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">

    <!-- Google Fonts -->
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Montserrat" rel="stylesheet">

    <!-- Bootstrap CSS from a CDN. This way you don't have to include the bootstrap file yourself -->

    <!-- Allows <hr> tag to be seen 
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css"
    integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous"> 
    -->

    <!-- Prevents <hr> tag from being shown -->
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"
    integrity="sha384-EVSTQN3/azprG1Anm3QDgpJLIm9Nao0Yz1ztcQTwFspd3yD65VohhpuuCOmLASjC" crossorigin="anonymous">

    <!-- Your own stylesheet -->
    <!-- Want to put it beneath Bootstrap's CSS since want it to have superior priority-->
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
</head>
```

Hi, I'm new to learning html, css and bootstrap. I came across that a particular

---

tag would not appear. It turns out the link I was using to receive the bootstrap CSS was the problem.

I've tried: Changing the css properties of the hr to different colours (still wouldn't show). The problem gets isolated to the link for bootstrap. The unusual thing is that it doesn't work with the second link being bootstrap 5.0.2, but it works with the first link bootstrap 4.3.1.

I've also tried to mark the

---

css properties as !important on my own stylesheet placed beneath the bootstrap css.

Thank you for the help ^_^.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <title>Startup</title>

    <!-- Required meta tags -->
    <!-- Recommended to always add them -->
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">

    <!-- Google Fonts -->
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Montserrat" rel="stylesheet">

    <!-- Bootstrap CSS from a CDN. This way you don't have to include the bootstrap file yourself -->

    <!-- Allows <hr> tag to be seen 
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css"
    integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous"> 
    -->

    <!-- Prevents <hr> tag from being shown -->
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"
    integrity="sha384-EVSTQN3/azprG1Anm3QDgpJLIm9Nao0Yz1ztcQTwFspd3yD65VohhpuuCOmLASjC" crossorigin="anonymous">


    <!-- Your own stylesheet -->
    <!-- Want to put it beneath Bootstrap's CSS since want it to have superior priority-->
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
</head>

<body>
    <!-- 
        h-100 means you want the container to span the entire height of page
        Hence, you can get the the items aligned within the container at its center.
    -->
    <div class="container d-flex align-items-center h-100">

        <div class="row">

            <!-- 
                Use col-12 since bootstrap grid system has 12 slots per row
                using col-12, ensures your div spans the entire row.
            -->
            <header class="text-center col-12">
                <h1 class="text-uppercase"><strong>The biggest startup event of the year</strong></h1>
            </header>

            <div class="buffer col-12"></div>

            <section class="text-center col-12">
                <hr>
                <a href="https://mailchi.mp/b24dbfe7c665/kimchilettuce">
                    <button class="btn btn-primary btn-xl">Find out more</button>
                </a>
            </section>
        </div>

    </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Below is my css file

```
body,
html {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
    background: url(header.jpg) no-repeat center center fixed; 
    -webkit-background-size: cover;
    -moz-background-size: cover;
    -o-background-size: cover;
    background-size: cover;
}

h1 {
    color: #e2dbdb;
    font-size: 3rem;
}

hr {
    border-color: #F05F44;
    border-width: 3px;
    max-width: 75px;
}

.buffer {
    height: 10rem;
}

.btn {
    font-weight: 700; /*This is different from font size. This specifies how thick the words are*/
    border-radius: 300px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
}

.btn-primary {
    background-color: #F05F44;
    border-color: #F05F44;
}

.btn-primary:hover {
    background-color: #ee4b08;
    border-color: #ee4b08;
    border-width: 4px;
}

.btn-xl {
    padding: 1rem 2rem;
}
```

[When using bootstrap css 4.3.1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CSFYt.jpg)

[When using boostrap css 5.0.2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Dypc7.jpg)

Comment: The issue might be in the HTML code in the <body>. Please share your full code.

Comment: It's working with 5.0.2 bootstrap css, check this: https://jsfiddle.net/bzkr68x4/1/

Comment: What is the value set for `display` property of the `parent` element?

Comment: @Mohamed

I added my full code. Note the behaviour when you switch between the style sheets that are marked with <!-- Allows <hr> tag to be seen  --> and <!-- Prevents <hr> tag from being shown -->. 

The orange <hr> tag will dissappear.

Comment: @Shyam I added my full code :) with an explanation in the comments.

Answer (score 0):

This works fine for me
Please share your body part of the webpage. The error might be there.

```css
h1 {
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <title>Startup</title>

  <!-- Required meta tags -->
  <!-- Recommended to always add them -->
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no" />

  <!-- Google Fonts -->
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Montserrat" rel="stylesheet" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-EVSTQN3/azprG1Anm3QDgpJLIm9Nao0Yz1ztcQTwFspd3yD65VohhpuuCOmLASjC" crossorigin="anonymous" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css" />
</head>

<body>
  <h1>Sample text</h1>
  <hr />
  <h1>Sample text</h1>
  <hr />
  <h1>Sample text</h1>
  <hr />
</body>

</html>
```

Hope this helps!